# Send SMS from Android on PC

Tags: windows, gratis, android, web-apps, sms

I am looking for a way to send SMS messages from my Android phone on my PC running Windows. I would also prefer if I could view my send SMS history on my PC as well.

Doesn't matter if it's wired or wirelessly. I would prefer a free option and it should run on Android 4.4.x and Windows 7/8.

Comment: I don't have any preference there. It can be either

Comment: Oh, there are lots of them. [Specific to this purpose](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid#group_670), or [covering much more](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement). So any specific requirements to narrow down candidates? ;)

Comment: Can I send .apk to my device with any of them?

Comment: @Izzy [PushBullet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android) was recently updated to also incorporate sending SMS (not just replying to them). You might want to add it to the list :)

Comment: @Timmy thanks for the pointer! It was already in one of the other lists (part 2 of the [Remote Droide](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid) collection). Linked it to the "Specific" list from above now as well ;)

Comment: AFAIC I use Google Voice, I like the integration within Gmail + cheap international calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/)

Manage your Android and send/receive texts from computer.

This is a great app - you [install it on your phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), and go to http://web.airdroid.com/ or the IP address displayed on the app on the phone.

AirDroid allows you to manage your phone as well, so you can:

- send APK files,
- locate/wipe your phone if you lose your phone,
- upload files,
- send a URL,
- send something to the clipboard,
- manage apps,
- access the camera,
- take screenshots,
- download files from the phone

The communication features:

- view SMS messages
- send SMS messages
- call people
- view call logs

It is free, runs on any browser, and doesn't require registration (although you get *more* - yes, more! -  features if you do), it also requires internet connection on both devices.

[image]